# DoReferenceTransaction - Re Billing failure with 15005

Tags: php, paypal

I am using DoReferenceTransaction and randomly it fails even after using most updated billing transaction id. Failure rate is about 30% to 50% on daily bases. Everytime we get 15005 error.

We provide online product which is initially on 15 day trial period and then based on usage we charge user by DoReferenceTransaction. Payment and frequency varies based on usage.

To authorize credit card for 15 day trial period, we do $0.01 authorization, capture and refund by DoDirectPayment API. After 15 day user will be charged by automated cron execution with most updated transaction id from PayPal. At this point we see failure about 30% to 50% on daily bases with below error. Product price are up to $350 so we do not make full amount authorization instead 1 cent authorization, capture and refund and further transaction by DoReferenceTransaction based on usage.

Error/PayPal Response

```
TIMESTAMP=2012-09-27T12:38:36Z 
CORRELATIONID=e25f624542dc 
ACK=Failure 
VERSION=64 
BUILD=3719653 
L_ERRORCODE0=15005 
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=ProcessorDecline 
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Thistransactioncannotbeprocessed. 
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error 
L_ERRORPARAMID0=ProcessorResponse 
L_ERRORPARAMVALUE0=0051 
AMT=44.95 
CURRENCYCODE=USD 
AVSCODE=S 
CVV2MATCH=P
```

Please help me to understand and rectify this issue. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: "The transaction was declined by the issuing bank, not PayPal. The merchant should attempt another card" 
Are you sure that the error is really caused by you?

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes

Comment: Exactly; as 'L_ERRORPARAMVALUE0' indicates, you got a 0051 response back. Here is a list I quickly googled that has a list of common decline codes: http://www.bluefinsupport.com/esupport/?_a=knowledgebase&_j=questiondetails&_i=24

Comment: To add, because you're authorizing for $0.01 and then attempting to charge up to $350, I'm not surprised you're seeing many 51's. If you'd do a $350 authorization, you'd probably see a decline at that stage already.

Comment: I have debit card which fails in the same manner on 1 cent authorization even with sufficient balance. 
I saw on bluefinsupport and 0051 means insufficient balance but that is not the case here. It's not clear what's going on. Please advice.

 TIMESTAMP=2012-09-18T18:20:14Z 
 CORRELATIONID=794b24121c249 
 ACK=Failure 
 VERSION=64 
 BUILD=3587318 
 L_ERRORCODE0=15005 
 L_SHORTMESSAGE0=ProcessorDecline 
 L_LONGMESSAGE0=Thistransactioncannotbeprocessed. 
 L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error 
 L_ERRORPARAMID0=ProcessorResponse 
 L_ERRORPARAMVALUE0=0051 
 AMT=0.01 
 CURRENCYCODE=USD 
 AVSCODE=U 
 CVV2MATCH=M